# Best practice to deploy a node server

Tags: node.js, linux, server

I've been busy for days trying to figure out an approach to running a node server on a production system.
Since I am not a system admin, my knowledge is limited.

My question is, what best practice should be applied when running one, or more node server on my machine?

Should I write a service that monitors the node server and restarts it automatically in case it goes down or in case the machine restarts?

And if I have local updates which I push to the server, how should I best restart the node server?

I have already googled, but not really come to my desired results

Comment: You can give [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) a try.

Comment: @pzaenger I read that it is not necessary anymore, since systemctl is installed on almost any distro

Comment: _Should I write a service that monitors the node server and restarts it automatically in case it goes down or in case the machine restarts?_ PM2 does it all for you.

Comment: Alright. I will take a look on it